# how to get value in select box with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get value from select box and put that value to text box. and i tried with jquery but this is doesn't work. Here's my code :

```
<select name="a[0]">
   <option value=1>AA</option>
   <option value=2>BB</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="val[0]">

<select name="a[1]">
   <option value=1>AA</option>
   <option value=2>BB</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="val[1]">
```

my jquery :

```
$("[name=a]").change(function(){
  var d = $(this).val();
  console.log(d);
  $("[name=val]").val(d);
});
```

i want to put value form select box and put that value to each textbox..

Comment: Which value you want to get, the selected value?

Comment: value from select box..

Comment: Change the name attributes to something useful. What you're doing now will cause constant issues for you.

Comment: what if you have 100's of select elements!! You'll index them with `1` , `2` `....`  !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select name="a[0]">
   <option >AA</option>
   <option>BB</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="val[0]">

<select name="a[1]">
   <option >AA</option>
   <option >BB</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="val[1]">
```

JS

```
 $("select").change(function(){
 var d = $(this).find( "option:selected" ).text();
 $(this).next("input[type='text']").val(d);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/byg9e71v/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/byg9e71v/

Use

```
$("select[name^=a]").change(function(){
  var d = $(this).val();
  console.log(d);
});
```

Comment: You will get 1 and 2 in console because you assigned 1 and 2 value to the options :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the following select lists and their text inputs dynamically, here is a sample on how to do it:

```
<select name="a_0" onclick='onselectlistclick("0")'>
       <option value=1>AA</option>
       <option value=2>BB</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="val_0">

    <select name="a_1" onclick='onselectlistclick("1")'>
       <option value=1>AA</option>
       <option value=2>BB</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="val_1">


    <script>
    function onselectlistclick(id) {
        $("#val_"+ id).val($("#a_" + id + " option:selected").val());
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace Your Code With this

```
 $("select").change(function(){
 var d = $(this).find( "option:selected" ).text();
 console.log(d);
});
```

Comment: If You Want the value the just replace the text() with val()

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good way to make index of element's name. Rather you can get the selected value and set it to it's immediate next text element,

```
$("select[name=a]").change(function(){
     // get index of your select control
     console.log($(this).index("select"));

     // this line will set the selected value to it's immediate next element. You can also handle on which elements you want to show the selected value by specifying the type ,name or class of the element.
     $(this).next().val($(this).val());
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/x2ntkq2q/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

> $("[name^=a]") - attribute name starts with
>
> $("[name*=a]") - attribute name contains
>
> $(this).next() - next element of this

```
$(function () {
     $("[name^=a]").change(function () {
         var d = $(this).val();
            console.log(d);
            $(this).next().val(d);
      });
});
```